# Building cpython 3.6 from souce brakes at final linking stage `.L1529'

Tags: python, linker, cpython

When compiling cpython-3.6 from source using makepkg on Arch Linux the build proceeds fine until the final linking step.  I end up failing with the following error:

```
gcc -pthread -Wl,-O0,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-O0,-sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o Programs/_testembed Programs/_testembed.o -L. -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1529'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1566'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1521'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1568'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1491'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1493'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1530'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1532'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1534'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1499'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1497'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1495'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1579'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1575'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1538'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1573'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1577'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1536'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1571'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1482'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1506'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1508'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1541'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1500'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1504'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1543'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1580'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1488'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1486'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1600'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1502'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1484'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1549'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1586'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1547'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1584'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1588'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1545'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1582'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1513'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1552'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1515'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1554'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1511'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1550'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1517'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1556'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1591'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1597'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1595'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1599'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1519'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1558'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1593'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1524'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1561'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1526'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1563'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1522'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1528'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1565'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1520'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1569'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1567'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1490'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1492'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1531'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1533'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1535'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1570'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1498'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1496'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1494'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1576'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1539'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1574'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1578'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1537'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1572'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1507'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1540'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1509'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1542'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1501'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1505'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1544'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1581'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1487'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1485'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1489'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1503'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1483'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1587'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1548'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1585'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1589'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1546'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1583'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1514'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1553'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1516'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1555'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1590'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1512'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1551'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1518'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1557'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1592'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1510'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1598'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1596'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1559'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1594'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1525'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1562'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1527'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1564'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1523'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1560'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:551: python] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1529'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1566'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1521'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1568'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1491'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1493'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1530'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1532'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1534'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1499'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1497'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1495'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1579'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1575'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1538'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1573'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1577'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1536'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1571'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1482'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1506'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1508'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1541'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1500'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1504'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1543'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1580'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1488'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1486'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1600'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1502'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1484'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1549'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1586'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1547'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1584'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1588'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1545'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1582'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1513'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1552'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1515'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1554'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1511'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1550'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1517'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1556'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1591'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1597'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1595'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1599'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1519'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1558'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1593'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1524'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1561'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1526'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1563'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1522'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1528'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1565'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1520'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1569'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1567'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1490'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1492'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1531'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1533'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1535'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1570'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1498'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1496'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1494'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1576'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1539'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1574'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1578'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1537'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1572'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1507'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1540'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1509'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1542'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1501'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1505'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1544'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1581'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1487'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1485'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1489'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1503'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1483'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1587'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1548'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1585'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1589'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1546'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1583'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1514'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1553'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1516'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1555'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1590'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1512'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1551'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1518'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1557'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1592'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1510'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1598'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1596'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1559'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1594'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1525'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1562'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1527'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1564'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1523'
./libpython3.6m.so: undefined reference to `.L1560'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:697: Programs/_testembed] Error 1
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
```

Here is a link to the source files I used in attempting to build the project: https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/python

What does this error mean? and what should I do to make the build function properly?

Thanks,

-Dave

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the linking problem is triggered on my system by including the --enable-optimizations flag in the ./configure script.  Configuring and then compiling my program without optimizations corrected the linking errors.

-Dave